# Given trigonometric function, find largest and smallest values

Tags: trigonometry

In the function $f(x)=\frac{k\cos{x}+1}{\sin^2{x}}$ where $x$ ranges over all real numbers except integers multiple of $\pi$ and $k$ is a constant, we have $f(x)>0$ for all values where $f(x)$ is defines. Find the positive integer difference between the largest and smallest possible values of $k$.

$\textbf{Thoughts}$ 
I'm not sure how to approach this problem. At first, I thought that that $f(x)$ was periodic, but then I saw the words "largest and smallest". Next, I thought of plugging in values. However, this wasn't possible. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is from an active contest on artofproblemsolving – are you supposed to be getting help on the internet?

Comment: I have not signed up for this active contest though. I prefer to solve problems from afar. Plus, I don't want to be judged by other AoPS members. For example : "Oh my god. Look at {insert name}. He only got a score of {insert low score}." I hate to see this happen, to anyone as a matter of fact.

Comment: The other thing to think of is whether it's OK for people who have signed up for the contest to be seeing the answers here because you posted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing here is that $k\cos(x)+1$ should never be negative or $0$. Now $\cos(x)$ will range from $-1$ to $1$.  Find $k$ from these conditions.
So look at the extreme cases. When $\cos(x)$ is $-1$, what extreme value of $k$ still lets $k\cos(x)+1$ be bigger than $0$? Is this value of $k$ included in the interval? What about when $\cos(x)$ is $1$? This should give you a sense as to what you should do.

Comment: So the lowest possible value is $0$?

Comment: The lowest value is given by taking $\cos(x)$ to be $1$. So we have $k+1>0$, which means $k>-1$. So no.

Comment: And the maximum value is $1$?

Comment: The maximum value is given by taking $\cos(x)$ to be $-1$. $-k+1>0$, so $k<1$. Do note that neither $-1$ or $+1$ are acceptable though (so they are not included in the range).

Comment: So the answer is $\boxed{2}$